# Retrieve several values using an equivalent to the 'match' function

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c('j','g','e'), c(5,8,3))
colnames(df1) <- c('person', 'number')

df2 <- data.frame(c('p','j','w','e','j','e','j'), c('a','b','c','f','l','m','n'))
colnames(df2)<-c('person','other')
```

And I want to retrieve values from `df2$'other'` based on matches between `df1$'person'` and `df2$'person'`. I used the following code:

```
result <- df2[match(df1$person, df2$'person'), 'other']
```

But I only obtain the value from the first match.

Is there any easy way, if possible in 'base R', to obtain all the matches? In this case, three values from `'j'` and two values from `'e'`. I'm working with big dataframes so I'm looking for an economic and fast solution.
When I use this I got all the entries for `'j'`:

```
df2$'person'=='j'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match will only give the first match.
In your case `merge` will give the desired result.

```
merge(df1, df2)
#  person number other
#1      e      3     f
#2      e      3     m
#3      j      5     b
#4      j      5     l
#5      j      5     n
```

Comment: But what can I do if the columns have different names?

Comment: You can given them with `by`, `by.x` (col names of first data.frame) and `by.y`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `%in%`:

```
df2[ df2$person %in% df1$person, ]
# or without column names, compare 1st columns
# df2[ df2[[1]] %in% df1[[1]], ]

#   person other
# 2      j     b
# 4      e     f
# 5      j     l
# 6      e     m
# 7      j     n
```